# Are helper methods not available in Resque Workers within a Functional Test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing, resque, worker

For some reason, none of my helper methods are available within the *views* my Resque worker is performing as specfied by a Functional test.

I was wondering if anyone else noticed this, and what a possible workaround could be?

In my test :

```
assert_queued(EmailTemplatePdfWorker)
Resque.run!
```

In my view rendered by email_template_pdf_worker.rb :

```
- raise 'this seriously does not work' if !(defined? newline_to_br)
```

*Where `newline_to_br` is a method defined in my application_helper.rb.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you didn't load up the view helper you want to use in your Mailer:

```
class EmailTemplatePdfWorker < ActionMailer::Base
  add_template_helper(ApplicationHelper)

  #...
end
```

Comment: I had thought of this, but it didn't suffice. Thanks Winfield!